# Talend - Where to find source code of internal library used by Talend?

Tags: talend

I am trying to locate the source code of internal library used by Talend.

The component tFileCopy is using org.talend.FileCopy

The Jar file is located at:

https://artifacts-oss.talend.com/nexus/content/repositories/TalendOpenSourceRelease/org/talend/libraries/filecopy/2.0.0/

and

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.talend.libraries/filecopy/2.0.0

But when I extract the Jar file, there is no source code.

Can anyone please help to locate the source code of this library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talend source code is hosted at GitHub https://github.com/Talend

There are many different repositories inside it.

I was able to find "org.talend.FileCopy" source code as below.

Step-1: Go into a particular repository
https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se

Step-2: Click on "Go to File"
[image]

Step-3: Type the name of the class you are looking for and open the file appearing in search result.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find source code for Talend Components in /plugin repository of your talend studio.
Somewhere like :

```
\Talend-Studio\plugins\org.talend.designer.components.localprovider_xx\components\tFileCopy
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, I was looking for sourcecode of "org.talend.FileCopy" which is used by tFileCopy component. I was able to find it after some search and I have posted it.

Comment: Yes, this is the same java file I think. Updated with a screenshot.

Comment: In case of 7.3.1 BD version, I am not able to see the FileCopy.java. It is just showing the *.class file.